# Someone who keeps one day Yom Tov Cooking on Chol HaMoed for someone else's Yom Tov Sheini

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul, chol-hamoed

It says in SA OC Siman 539 Sif 11 (in the Rema) that one may buy things on Chol HaMoed that are needed for the Yom Tov Sheini (of the last days of Yom Tov), which is rabbinic in nature for those living outside of Israel, and is not Yom Tov at all for those living in Israel. Rebbe Akiva Eager there writes that the Tur says one is permitted to "prepare". Rebbe Akiva Eager then says that the Tur is implies that even something that is a malacha, like cooking, may be done on Chol HaMoed for Yom Tov Sheini.

In M"B Sif-Katan 38, the author writes that we don't say "yom tov sheini might really be a weekday and therefore it is [ossur](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) to do something chol hamoed for its needs". Rather, it is [muter](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) to do something on Chol HaMoed for the purpose of Yom Tov Sheini.

My question is: Is an Israeli keeping only 7 days of the Chag allowed to cook on Chol HaMoed for *someone else's* Yom Tov Sheini (which is Isru Chag for the one cooking)? Even though the Yom Tov Sheini will be a weekday for the one cooking, for the other person it's Yom Tov and would have the [heter](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/585) of the Rema and Rebbe Akiva Eager (with the explanation of the M"B). What sources are there on this? What savarah (logic) could be said (in favor of one way or the other)?

Comment: I edited your question because I originally thought you were asking about cooking ON Yom Tov Sheini for someone who is keeping it, not cooking IN PREPARATION for the upcoming Yom Tov Sheini.

Comment: @SethJ, you restricted the question so it asks only about people currently in Israel.

Comment: @msh210, Oops, that was my assumption from the original phrasing leaking into my editing.  Please correct it for me. I'm about to log off.

Comment: @SethJ It could also be an Israeli in Chu"l who is only visiting and keeping one day.

Comment: I'm still not in love with the title. It isn't clear if this is on the second day of the Chag/first day of Chol Hamo'ed and he's cooking for that day, or if this is any day of Chol HaMo'ed and he's doing it for the 8th day.

Comment: Hey, btw, can you cook during Chol HaMo'ed Sukkoth for Shemini 'Atzereth? Any reason to think this would be different?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Yirmeyahu Kaganoff writes in [an article](http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1558) that the one keeping a single day of Yom Tov may *not* cook on Chol haMoed for the last day's meals of one who is keeping two days of Yom Tov. The meals may either be prepared by the two-day-er, prepared by the one-day-er after Yom Tov has ended for him/her, or the one-day-er may prepare excessively large portions of food for consumption on his/her last day of Yom Tov, with the leftovers being served the next day.

Comment: This is now a cobweb link. When you can, see if you can update it.

Comment: You wrote "prepared by the one-day-er after Yom Tov has ended for him/her," -- does this apply to an Israeli in Chu"l cooking on the second day of yom tov for an American? The day is chol hamo'ed for the Israeli and according to halachipedia "There is what to rely on for an Isreali who is outside Israel on the second day of Yom Tov in private to carry muktzeh on Yom Tov, light a match, or turn on a light." Can I ask my Israeli visitor to do cooking related melacha on the second day of Pesach, and benefit from it?