# Melacha for people observing Yom Tov Sheni in Israel

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, melacha-creative-work, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz

Can a non-resident of Israel keeping 2 days or 1.5 days of *yom tov* benefit from melacha (forbidden-type labor) done for him by an Israeli on the second day?

Comment: Related (but not the same question) is http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27764. I recommend you see there for an example of clearly including in the question what you already know and what you are lacking.

Answer (score 4):

Rav Moshe Feinstein ([OC 3:73](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=379)) writes that there is a machlokes in the Shaarei Teshuva (496:3) about thi, but writes that the halacha follows the authorities who prohibit asking others to perform melacha on their behalf.

Rav Ovadia Yosef (Chazon Ovadia, Yom Tov p138) disagrees, writing that one is allowed to ask Israelis to perform melacha.